# How to avoid suspension of iOS app on background transition?

Tags: iphone, ios, background-process, suspend

I know that iOS normally suspends the app on going to background. And there are ways to continue execution mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20).
But I found an app **Saavn**, which continues to download even after going to background.

- Although it's a music app, but for audio service to run on background an audio must be playing. And it continues downloading even if no audio is playing.
- This also can't be done through `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`, as it only allows completion of a single fixed-length task. But in this app it continues to download infinitely till the whole playlist is downloaded.
- And I also don't think it would be `UIBackgroundModes = fetch` because it downloads very large playlists with hundreds of songs(which are definately not samll fetches).

So, is there any other way to continue background execution(**without violating apple's policies**), NOT mentioned in Apple's developer's reference?

Comment: you should first set property in info.plist for app and try it....

Comment: @kokx are you saying to set the `UIBackgroundModes` to `fetch`? But will that work for continuously downloading such large content?

Comment: No one here has any idea?

Comment: At least the developers of *Saavn* can share their knowledge!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this documentation, it explains different scenarios https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html